# Index Error When Deleting Lines From A txt File

Tags: python

```
        lines = file.readlines()

        del lines[68]
```

This is the code im using to delete the lines, I have already opened the file it works with lots of other stuff. When I run this code it pops up with an index error when Im deleting lines in the middle of the txt file. I ve tried many versions of deleting lines in the txt file but none of them work. Any ideas?

Comment: If the file has 68 lines or less, then `lines[68]` is out of bounds (remember that Python lists start at index 0).

Comment: `print(len(lines))` is helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to delete lines in the actual file, or just in the python list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short**

You can add `f.seek(0)` before `f.readlines()`, and try your code again.

**Long explain**

I tried your code and it seems working normally when deleting single element in `lines`.

Did you use `f.readlines()` multiple times? In that case, the second time this method will return `empty list` because the first call already move the `cursor` to end of file.

To read the `file` again, you have to use this method `f.seek(0)` to move the cursor back to the begin of file before calling `f.readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

How about testing if the txt file has 69 lines at all ?

```
def delete_line(path, number)
    f = opne(path, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    if len(lines) - 1 < number:
        print("The file %s has not a line number %d" % (path, number))
    else:
        del lines[number]
    return lines
```

Use it like this:

```py
lines = delete_line("path/to/file/you/want/to/delete/a/line/from.txt", 68)
```

If your file was long enough, you will have the file minus the specified line saved in `lines`, else a warning will be printed and the value of `lines` will be the unmodified file.

Comment: @Liq if you mean how to use the function, see my edit. But you haven't got to use my function, it was just to demonstrate how it's done.